# Why is there no [asp.net-core-mvc] tag?

Tags: feature-request, tags

As I have noticed, there are only tags such as: [asp.net](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/asp.net), [asp.net-mvc-3](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc-3) and [asp.net-mvc-4](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc-4). However, there is no tag for [asp.net-core-mvc](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-core-mvc). Why so? I believed it is a must-have to separate the question into a new category with different issues. I cannot create a new tag due to my reputation. Am I wrong?

Comment: I asked this in chat, got no real response. Good to ask this question!

Comment: Relevant question here (posted by the OP): http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/133616/reading-and-displaying-an-image-from-a-folder

Answer (score 1):

.NET core is (very) new. I don't imagine it has many posts yet, nor can I see anyone using .NET Core MVC in production yet, which is probably why it is not posted here.

I think it'd be a good idea for a tag. We may also want to create [ef-core](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ef-core), which is the newer version of entity framework and supersedes EF6, and potentially [.net-core](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/.net-core) itself>?